# Preferred method for installing Oracle Sun JAVA in 16.04.3 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, java, oracle

Based on Google searches I've found two methods:

I successfully used the method described via http://www.duinsoft.nl/packages.php?t=en previously in Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS:

1. Add the duinsoft repository:
   `$ sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list`
   Add line: `deb http://www.duinsoft.nl/pkg debs all`

   Alternatively this can be accomplished with the command: `echo "deb http://www.duinsoft.nl/pkg debs all" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/duinsoft.list`
2. Import gpg key for repository: `$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 5CB26B26`
3. Install JAVA:
   `$ sudo apt-get update`
      `$ sudo apt-get install update-sun-jre`

**OR** the seemingly "official" method which I've never tried

1. Add the Oracle repository:
   `$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`
2. Install JAVA:
   `$ sudo apt-get update`
   `$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`

Is there a reason to choose one method over the other?

Answer (score 0):

Both of these are not 100% official. One uses a custom repository (questionable), the other a PPA (less questionable, but still not fully official. The official method includes:

1. Going to java.com and finding the link to the linux version.
2. You will notice that there is 4 versions of the package, x64 and x86. Find the appropriate one for your PC, then choose the .tar.gz format when downloading.
3. Extract the .tar.gz archive into a folder and chmod +x each file if needed. Then, this is technically done, but you need to be in the directory to invoke java. To fix this, you have to...
4. Copy the directory to a place where anyone can see it and recursively set the permissions so that anyone can access it. A good place to copy the directory would be /usr/bin/java or /usr/java and while technically against the FHS, it works. Then, open a new terminal and invoke java. If the command is not found, then open /etc/environment and with path, use :. Java is now installed.

Comment: ok, but the advantage of the two methods I presented are that they will update "automatically" (or through `apt-get update` / `apt-get upgrade` anyway), whereas your method requires me to manually download and install JAVA with each new release, correct?  back to my question though, is there any difference in effect between the two methods presented?  I also thought that duinsoft.nl is considered a very respected / trusted source

Comment: @Daniel You are correct about the auto-updates. The difference of the two methods depends. For one, the repositories can be outdated or can bring malicious software into your system. If you trust the source, though, there is no real difference. Don't forget, though, that my method will work on almost any distro, with minor adjustments.